# Why is virtualenvwrapper creating paths related to python2 instead of python3?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I updated the versions of mkvirtualenv and virtualenv

> $ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

because my whole life I only used Python 2, and wanted to use -now- Python 3. The `virtualenvwrapper` had some issues.

Then I tried creating a virtual environment for my python3 installation:

> $ mkvirtualenv py3test -p /usr/bin/python3

The environment is created in `~/.virtualenvs/py3test`. Once active, I want to install a package I made:

> (py3test)$ pip install python-cantrips
>   (py3test)$ pip freeze

And the package is appropriately installed. Then I install `ipython` and run it:

> (py3test)$ pip install ipython
>   (py3test)$ ipython

And I enter `ipython` appropriately. But then I...

```
import cantrips
```

And it explodes with an `ImportError`. Then I check `sys.path`. And the issue is here: **sys.path includes a path like: '/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/py3test/lib/python2.7/site-packages'**. I don't remember whether the path is exact or not, since I am not in such computer right now. But I can have one thing for sure: the environment was created with python3 (the directory is not python2.7 but python3.5 in my virtualenv).

So: Why is virtualenv creating an environment for python3 but adding me the paths as if it was a python2.7 environment instead?

Comment: Are you tried to use `pip3`? If you wanna have env for Python3 run this `python3 -m venv ENV`

Comment: When you just run `python` which version is shown?

Comment: @KlausD. The default python version I use, is Python 2.7. Should I change the default python option before running mkvirtualenv? What's the purpose of the -p option in virtualenv if so?

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

There was no issue with `virtualenv` or `virtualenvwrapper`. The issue was with `ipython`. Actually, there is no issue specifically with `ipython` but with the way the scripts are accessible inside a virtualenv.

Globally, I had `ipython` installed (which works with the global `python27`). When I installed `ipython` in my local python3 environment, the (shell) path was not updated until I somehow refresh the environment again (e.g. deactivating, activating again). So when I tried again, the `ipython` was the appropriate (the local `ipython` in my environment with 3.5), and the generated path was the expected one.